# cannot open any file in MacGDBp

Tags: php, macos, debugging

I’ve just downloaded MacGDBp on my Mac but cannot use it because I cannot open or read any file from it. In the « File » menu, only « Open Recent » (pointing to an empty list) and « Close » are enabled.
 I also tried using « Open as » on a file of my project to open it with MacGdBp, but that was refused also by the system.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Window -> Breakpoints -> "+" -> Open a file on your local machine. View the file in the breakpoints window and set a breakpoint where you want.

MacGDBp -> Preferences -> Paths -> "+". Set local to the project root on your local machine, and set remote to the project root on the machine running the code you are debugging.

Now when you set a breakpoint in a local file and have a matching path entry, MacGDBp will set a breakpoint in the corresponding remote file.

The [MacGDBp doc](https://www.bluestatic.org/software/macgdbp/help.php#remote-paths) helped me find this answer.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I am new to this program but I don't believe that it how it is intended to be used (pretty sure all OSX apps have the usual File menu options but they are greyed out if an app doesn't use them).

Once you start MacGDBp it starts listening for connections on port 9000 using the DBGp protocol (the PHP Xdebug extension uses that protocol to connect to a remote debugger such as MacGDBp). Once it receives a connection, MacGDBp will display the current file that is being executed. I have not yet figured out how to open new files in MacGDBp without doing this -- may not be possible.

So the key is to configure whatever is running your code to connect to MacGDBp.